# DB2's JSON capabilities

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor, db2, informix

I'm writing an application in MeteorJS, which requires use of MongoDB. However, I'd really like to use an SQL database, as my data is highly relational, and I could make use of features like views.

I see that IBM has a Mongo wireline driver which natively emulates Mongo i.e. you can create a frontend that thinks it's communicating to a Mongo database, while in reality, it's being backed by an SQL database. This, to me, seems ideal, at least until Meteor supports a native relational backend.

Both DB2 and Informix have Mongo drivers, and my question is this: have any of you used the JSON and Mongo driver capabilities of either of these DBs and are there limitations or factors to consider? This is a greenfield project so there's no legacy database that needs to be supported.

I'd prefer to use DB2, as Informix appears to be a legacy product and I'm hesitant to start a brand new project with technology I'll have trouble finding trained staff for. Ironically, however, it seems that Informix has deeper support for JSON, including full two-way conversion of JSON to relational tables and back, indexing, etc. (even sharding and replication)

My reading of DB2 is that currently it only supports JSON as an additional JSON/BSON field into which all JSON data will go, but without automatic two-way access to the other relational columns. Is this correct? Anyone using DB2's JSON features?

I suspect in future versions, IBM will put better JSON support into DB2 (sort of how XML was gradually integrated), but I need something now. So my options for now, as I see them:

1. Use Informix with its better JSON support.
2. Use DB2 with less JSON support (unless I'm mistaken), and wait for
   new versions
3. Use MongoDB for now and wait for Meteor to support a
   relational DB
4. Any other options?

Comment: There's almost no way this question can be other than opinion-based.  Your assessment of Informix is, sadly, rather too accurate for comfort.  If DB2 doesn't work for you, maybe using plain Mongo is most sensible.

Comment: I tried to make it as specific as possible to avoid being purely opinion-based or worse, become a flame war about one's favorite DB. Basically, if anyone has experiences with the JSON capability of DB2 or Informix and/or the Mongo wireline driver, I'd love to hear it, especially about the limitations or quirks that they've noticed. If they've used it in the setting of Meteor that would be even better :-)